# ¿Por qué los campos de mi formulario HTML no se envían al servidor?

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo un problema posiblemente sea un error sencillo pero no encuentro la razón.

Tengo este formulario en HTML.

```
<form method="post" action="send.php">
<p><input name="" type="text" id="name" name="user_name" value="Nombre"></p>
<p><input name="" type="email" id="mail" name="user_email" value="E-Mail"></p>
<p><input name="" type="text" id="phone" name="user_phone" value="Télefono"></p>
<p><textarea name="" id="msg" name="user_message" cols="" rows="7"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" /></p>
</form>
```

Y este código PHP.

```
<?php
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
$user_phone = $_POST['user_phone'];

$header = 'De: ' . $user_email . " \r\n";


$msg = "Este mensaje fue enviado por " . $user_name . ", su teléfono es " . $user_phone . " \r\n";
$msg .= "Su e-mail es: " . $user_email . " \r\n";
$msg .= "Mensaje: " . $_POST['user_message'] . " \r\n";
$msg .= "Enviado el " . date('d/m/Y', time());

$to = 'mail@mail.com';
$subject = 'Contacto desde Producciones111.com';


mail($to, $subject, utf8_decode($msg), $header);

header("Location: http://website.com/");

?>
```

Pero al enviar el formulario la información llega vacía al correo.

> Este mensaje fue enviado por , su teléfono es
>   Su e-mail es:
>   Mensaje:
>   Enviado el 09/03/2016

De esta forma, sin información registrada.

Comment: Te recomiendo validar el email recibido

Comment: y si he puesto el name una sola vez alguien tiene idea de por qué me llegan los campos al email vacíos???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que quitar el campo `name=""` porque lo estas usando dos veces!

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que en todos tus `input` has puesto el atributo **`name=""`** al principio

Mal:

```
<input name="" type="text" id="name" name="user_name" value="Nombre">
```

Mejor:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" value="Nombre">
```

Lo que sucede es que los valores no están siendo enviados al servidor ya que el `input` se considera sin nombre, y el nombre es la manera de identificar los valores individuales.

Comment: Mil gracias, un completo descuido no me fije en eso, ya resuelto, funciona perfecto!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Tus campos `name` no están definidos, siempre que envías datos, lo que rescatas es

```
$_POST['name'];
```

por tanto, tus formularios deben ser algo como

```
<input name="VALOR" type="text" id="name" name="user_name" value="Nombre">
```

Usando esto, en el script puedes usar

```
$_POST['VALOR'];
```

además, etás usando el campo 'name' 2 veces.